# How to work with realm database from not Activity Class

Tags: android, realm

I have written class that will done All what I want from Realm database
I've done it for design purpose

this is My class

```
public class workwithDB implements Serializable {
Realm realm;


public workwithDB() {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}



public LinkedList<String> getTripsName() {
    RealmResults<Trip> trips = realm.where(Trip.class).findAll();
    LinkedList<String> TripsName = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <trips.size();i++)
        TripsName.add(trips.get(i).getTripName());
    return TripsName;
}}
```

Then I declare Instance variable of workwithDB in My mainActivity class 
And I initialization it in onCreate method

But when I Run My app there is error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kha/kha.al.Activities.MainActivity}: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
```

And I can not use this line in not Activity Class

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
```

How I can fix this error

Thank you

Comment: Realmmigrations are typically handled in your `extends Application` class

Comment: Sidenote: your design will not work. All instances of a realm **must** be closed when youre done with them

Comment: You can read more about how to handle Realm instances here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances